# MySQL TRUNCATE(double, 4) is modifying value instead of truncating

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to truncate a double with 4 decimals, but I get the last digit rounded (and the double has 4 decimals only!)

double: 
-2.5805

```
SELECT TRUNCATE(double, 4) FROM `table`
```

Result: 
-2.5804

What's more interesting is that:

```
SELECT TRUNCATE(mycol, 4) AS col1, TRUNCATE(-2.5805, 4) AS col2
FROM mytable
```

returns:

```
col1    |  col2
--------+--------
-2.5804 | -2.5805
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/68183/3)

Answer (score 3):

The double data type is a floating point type, meaning these numbers are not stored as exact numbers. As MySQL documentation on [floating point types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html) explains:

> Because floating-point values are approximate and not stored as exact
>   values, attempts to treat them as exact in comparisons may lead to
>   problems. They are also subject to platform or implementation
>   dependencies.

This means that the number `-2.5805` is not an exact number when it is stored as a double. The truncate() function, however, returns an exact number with an exact number of digits. When the `-2.5805` (as double) is expanded, the 4th decimal digit is 4.

The `TRUNCATE(-2.5805, 4)` expression returns `-2.5805` because MySQL treats [numeric literals expressed with fixed number of decimal digits](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/number-literals.html) as decimal data type, which is an exact data type. Therefore, the `truncate()` function just simply returns the same number of decimal digits.